# Reference data sets to test neural network implementations

Tags: neural-networks

Is there any set of reference data sets that one can use to test an implementation of a neural network layer (e.g. CNN, RNN, LSTM, etc.), to ensure it is working ok?

Comment: You might want to post here: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yann LeCun gathered quite some networks with results for [MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/)

Answer (score 2):

You can find many datasets here:

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html

They are not especially for neural networks but you can look for those that fit your case. I have worked with the set air foil noise:

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Airfoil+Self-Noise

And tried a simple adaline and an MLP obtaining great results.

Hope it helps